# AEM Workflow process steps should not be shown to user after initiation

Tags: workflow, aem, usergroups

I have configured the workflow for a particular user group(author), who can only initiate the workflow, rest of the workflow steps should not be shown to user. In the current scenario if I am giving user to execute the workflow then all the process steps are showing in his page. I want to restrict the author to perform other process steps, they should only initiate the request only.

Please provide more information in the user group privileges so that I can allow or deny these rights to particular user.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post there your workflow model, so it would be easier to help you?

Comment: Can you please give more information about "Why are you using participant steps if you don't want your users to have the ability to see the steps?" You can use process steps and make sure the handler advance is checked, this way the workflow will be an automatic thing without user interaction

Answer (score 0):

To restrict access for users from this group to all steps (except triggering workflow), these steps should be assigned to other participant (like *administrators* group).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the steps to the wf initiator or you can use other participant selector and there you can specify the assignee of the workflow. This way you can define which groups have access to the dialog.

---